# How to generate SQL Script for pending migrations in code without dotnet command line tool

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

My boss asks me to create an executable file beside my project to generate SQL Script for pending migrations. But I don't want to use `dotnet ef migrations script $FROM $TO ....`
I want to generate them in my asp.net core application and after seeing changes, then migrate the db.
All solutions found on the internet were using dotnet command line tool. Do you know if there is a solution to generate migrations script in my application.

Thanks

Comment: Okay, this is might be a dumb question but what is wrong with using EF migrations to generate the script?  You can then run the scripts with SQLCMD if you want to - even on Linux.  If you are using an EF model first approach and trying to create scripts using another technique,  you are opening yourself up to the possibility that the script might be different from the model.

Comment: @GlennSills unfortunately, another department is responsible of Database operations and they want to review database changes before migrations executed. and we can't provide source code to them...

Comment: Well if you hand-code the scripts a developer has to write them. What is wrong with having a developer create the scripts using EF Migration and then providing those scripts to the other department? I feel your pain though. I've been in the situation where another group is responsible for the database and they are opposed to ORM.